# Carrot2 visualization in .NET project

Tags: carrot2

Is there any way that I can use Carrot2's visualization in my .Net project?

I cannot find anything other than a reference saying that the source code is not available. But can we use it?

Please help if you know the answer

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visualizations are JavaScript/HTML5 components, so if your .NET application is web-based, you should be able to use them in a straightforward way. If you develop a desktop application, you'd need to run the visualizations in an embedded browser component, much like Carrot2 Clustering Workbench does.